# Electron + Vue + msal-nodejs + Azure Ad: redirect URL issue

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, active-directory, electron

I'm building a desktop app using Electron and Vue as framework.

I also need to authenticate the user using Azure AD and I'm using msal-node.js as library to do that.

I'm able to authenticate with the server in azure and get the user info, but I cannot figure it out how to set the redirect URL.

First I have to say that the behaviour between dev and prod change drastically and I'm going to explain both scenarios and, in both of them I'm going to use history mode or not

**DEV - using createWebHistory**

Return Url in Azure and .env file: http://localhost:8080/

This is what I've got from the devTools during the normal navigation (no authenticated)

[image]

And this is what I've got after the authentication (the call to the API is successful):

[image]

[image]

Blank page in the app.

**DEV - using createWebHashHistory**

Return Url in Azure and .env file: http://localhost:8080/#/

After the authentication (failed):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Blank page in the app.

**PROD**

In prod I must use **createWebHasHistory** otherwise I've got blank page from the beginning.

The first problem I've got in production is the url itself.
When I create the window I call the following url:

```
await win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
```

In azure I cannot use the same url because it's not a valid url.

If I use just:

```
await win.loadURL('app://index.html')
```

I've got blank page

[image]

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found it's pretty simple. Probably it's not the most "elegant", but it works, at least for prod. In dev I've still got the same weird problem described above.

Basically I'm starting a node server (localhost:3031 for example), within the app itself, then I'm catching the redirect url with it (localhost:3031/redirect) and serving the internal url from it:

```
expressApp.get('/redirect', async (req, res) => {
  await win.loadURL('app://./index.html#about')
})
```

As I said, it works and I don't see any security issue with that, but, if you have any other idea or suggestion, please let me know.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I've found the issue with Dev as well. In order to authenticate I'm using what Microsoft is suggesting in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop).

If you look at the file [AuthProvider.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop#add-authentication-logic-to-your-app) there is this portion of code, at the beginning:

```
const CUSTOM_FILE_PROTOCOL_NAME = process.env.REDIRECT_URI.split(':')[0];
```

Down below, in the method "getTokenIteractive" there is this other piece of code that applies the new protocol:

```
protocol.registerFileProtocol(CUSTOM_FILE_PROTOCOL_NAME, (req, callback) => {
    const requestUrl = new URL(req.url)
    callback(path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${requestUrl.path}`))
  })
```

In Dev my REDIRECT_URI is "http://localhost:3031/redirect", but the app protocol must be "app" (or whatever you have chosen) in order to work with Vue. So, I've just wrapped this last method in a condition based on the environment and now everything works as expected everywhere.

I hope all this can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and your solution helped me out, thank you! Can I ask how you handled the logout redirect?

Also have you tried `onBeforeRequest` to handle the redirects, instead of a node server?

It was used as an example in an auth0 blog: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-electron-applications-with-openid-connect-and-oauth-2/

Comment: Please use comment option for messages likes that and discussing some things with any particular person

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have access to the project anymore and I cannot double check for you, but, as much as I remember the logout didn't require anything special, just redirect to the page you want to after calling the log out method, if I remember properly.
I hope I'm right and it can be useful to you.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the reply @Ale! 
@mrvol I wish I could, and I hesitated writing an answer. but stack overflow requires 50 reputation to use the comment option unless it's my own answer